# How to get the rectangles in the union of all monitors which's area arent contained in the monitors' area

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

i have a multi-monitor setup, and i made a big window for the game area of my program, and i wanna put rectangles that act as walls, so the player cannot go to the parts of the window which are out of bounds
for example the red parts here:

[image: the area of the rectangles i want]

i have code that works for this particular case, but in this case:

[image]

it doesn't work(when the screen's X/Y is greater than the other monitor's, and Width/Height is less than the other monitor's.

Probably there is some smart math to make this really easy, but i cant think of any smart way of doing this.

The code that works for the first part is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Screen.AllScreens.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X == Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Width)
                {
                    outOfBoundRekts.Add(new Rectangle(Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Y, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Width, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Y));
                    if (Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Height < Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Y + Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Height)
                    {
                        outOfBoundRekts.Add(new Rectangle(Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Height, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Y));
                    }
                }
                if (Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Y == Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Height)
                {
                    outOfBoundRekts.Add(new Rectangle(Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Height, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Height));
                    if (Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Width < Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X + Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Width)
                    {
                        outOfBoundRekts.Add(new Rectangle(Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Y, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Width, Screen.AllScreens[j].Bounds.Y));
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

since i use my monitors in the first way, it would be fine as it is right now, but i would like my code to be flexible, and i'm curious what solution this problem has.